# What's the best practice for spring boot parallel outgoing requests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency

I am building a Java Spring Boot (micro) service that basically have a single REST endpoint to retrieve data for some resource. To do that, per each incoming request I need to retrieve the information from about 3-5 external resources (caching and pre-retrieval of the data is not an option, as either caching won't help statistically and I must not store the data on my servers in any way).

So basically per each incoming request I need to generate 3-5 external service calls, and of course I wish to have those in parallel / concurrently. This is a very lightweight service, as it's mostly waiting on I/O responses.

**What's the best practice to do that?**

If I need to use some kind of thread pool, it means that if I need to support 200 parallel requests, then I need 600-1000 threads for the outgoing requests, which becomes a very heavy service just mostly waiting on I/O.

(for comparison, with Node.js this is easy, as I just use a `Promise.all(...)` per each, and I get great concurrency, however I wish to understand how the same can be achieved with Java Sprint-Boot)

Comment: I don't think your question is a good fit for SO - it's opinion-based, too broad, and in the end, it's mostly asking for library recommendations - all 3 are not a good fit. But you may want to read this blog post: [High-Concurrency HTTP Clients on the JVM](https://dzone.com/articles/high-concurrency-http-clients-on-the-jvm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new reactive functionality that was added in Spring 5.
You can use it in the latest spring boot versions.

for example have a look at this https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/